# Using OctaneRender with two different Nvidia GPUs (780ti & 580)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I have two GPUs in my system - a GTX 780ti and a GTX 580.

They are both recognised by Ubuntu and Octane, and both work on their own rendering in Octane. However, the problem is they wont work *together* in Octane as they should.

Every time I enable both of them in Octane, it switches to the 580 and shows the 780ti as 'failed', but then disabling the 580 in Octane allows the 780ti to work fine.

Interestingly, in the Additional Drivers window, the selected driver for each card switches up after trying to use them in Octane. Or even just doesn't show one of the cards at all.

Is there a way to force the cards to use the same driver?